# How to decide library install path on different linux systems?

Tags: cmake, installation, linux-distro

Fedora have dynamic libs on `/usr/lib64` and `/usr/lib`, for 64-bit and 32-bit libs separately; while 64-bit Debian install some 64-bit libraries on `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, but seems some 64-bit libs are still in `/usr/lib`.

This looks pretty messy. So when I write a cmake file for my project, how to decide the place for installing the compiled libs?

Comment: What are you looking for? Usually the `FIND_PACKAGE` command is used to determine the location of required libraries.

Comment: @JohannesS. I'm looking for the correct path to install my library

Comment: Sorry, I missed that when reading your question.

Comment: highly related: [How does CMake decide to make a lib or lib64 directory for installations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76517286/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html), you would typically use a variable such as `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` in your CMakeLists.txt files.