# How does CMake decide to make a lib or lib64 directory for installations?

Tags: unix, cmake

If I install the same CMake-based package (cxxopts) with the same compiler (gcc12) on two different Unix machines (CentOS & MacOS), one time I get a `prefix/lib` and the other a `prefix/lib64` directory.

Is there a way to predict what the lib directory is going to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does CMake decide to make a lib or lib64 directory for installations?

It's not so much up to CMake as it is up to the maintainers of a project where a target gets installed to (see the `DESTINATION` parameter of [the `install(...)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html)).

cxxopts uses GNUInstallDirs, which is a helper module provided by CMake defining conventional installation locations for different types of things. See [its CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts/blob/v3.1.1/CMakeLists.txt#L36) (`include(GNUInstallDirs)`) and [its cxxopts.cmake file](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts/blob/v3.1.1/cmake/cxxopts.cmake#L129) (`install(TARGETS cxxopts EXPORT ${targets_export_name} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})`).

From [the GNUInstallDirs docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html):

> `LIBDIR`
> object code libraries (lib or lib64)

---

> Is there a way to predict what the lib directory is going to be?

If the project uses GNUInstallDirs, yes. From [the CMake source code](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/blob/v3.26.4/Modules/GNUInstallDirs.cmake?ref_type=tags#L221):

> Override this default 'lib' with 'lib64' iff:
>
> - we are on Linux system but NOT cross-compiling
> - we are NOT on debian
> - we are NOT building for conda
> - we are on a 64 bits system
>
> reason is: amd64 ABI: https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI
> For Debian with multiarch, use `lib/${CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE}` if
> `CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE` is set (which contains e.g. "i386-linux-gnu"
> and `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is "/usr".
> See http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch

If you want to do a check at configure time of what this is, then check the `CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR` variable. Ex. `if("${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}" STREQUAL "lib64") ...`.

Answer (score 1):

The installation directory is determined from two parts.

- All files will be installed within the install directory determined by [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html). This variable can be set by the user when configuring the build and projects should respect that choice. The default on Linux for this is usually `/usr/local`, but you can set it to instead install to, say, a subfolder within your home directory.
- The directory structure within the install directory is usually determined by the project itself, with only limited configurability from the outside. Whether libraries get put into the `lib` or `lib64` subdirectory therefore depends on the individual project and there is no hard rule for predicting the directory layout from the outside.

The exact directory structure within the install directory is determined by the [`INSTALL` commands](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) given to CMake, in particular the `DESTINATION` field. Most projects follow common conventions here, but you will need to consult a project's documentation or its CMake files to figure out the exact layout.

The relevant INSTALL command for cxxopts can be found [here](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts/blob/c8c932f891a559a099198ec4a1fccf6110d6463a/cmake/cxxopts.cmake#LL129C95-L129C95).
Note that `cxxopts` uses CMake's [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) module to configure the directories, which follows the common GNU/Linux conventions. That module is also responsible for the distinction between `lib` and `lib64` here.

Comment: Interesting. So I could write a one-line (two-line?) `CMakeLists.txt` that loads `GNUInstallDirs` and prints `LIBDIR`?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout [Exactly](https://godbolt.org/z/zbqKcKTjd).

Comment: This is wrong. I'm building the same libraries on Ubuntu and Fedora, and they install to `lib` and `lib64` respectively. CMake determines this automatically somehow.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat This answer talks about the specifics of the CMake file for cxxopts. I thought I made that clear in the answer. I fail to see how the fact that another library may solve this differently impacts the correctness of what is stated in this answer.

Comment: Sorry, maybe "wrong" is a strong word, and I should've read the answer more thoroughly before saying that. It's just somewhat misleading. You say that it's up to the library, and its technically correct, but apparently most (?) libraries use this `GNUInstallDirs` module and thus share the common logic for determining the directory name.